# Migration from source YML: implode all values of each array element nested inside an parent array

Tags: 8, migrations

We are trying to pull in some data from an outside source that serves JSON.

The structure of said json is like this:

```
[
    {
        "name":"something",
        "desc":"some kind of desc.",
        "tags": [
            {
                "order":"3",
                "displayName":"Tag1"
            },
            {
                "order":"13",
                "displayName":"Tags 101"
            },
            {
                "order":"28",
                "displayName":"Dogs"
            }
        ]
    }, ...

]
```

We want to implode all tags.displayName values into one string.  I'll use the body field as an example. 
In the UI, if you view the content, "body" would be:

```
Tag1|Tags 101|Dogs
```

In the "fields" section of my migration source yml file:

```
name: tagsCollection
label: "tagsCollection"
selector: tags
```

Then, in the process section of the YML file I've tried this:

```
body:
    plugin: concat
    delimiter: "|"
    source:
     - stepsCollection
```

I've also looked into the iterator plugin.  Nothing seems to click.

If I do this in the process section of the yml file:

```
body: stepsCollection
```

body will be "Array" in the UX.  So it is aware that there is an array in that var.

What am I missing??  Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation examples of concat](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21migrate%21src%21Plugin%21migrate%21process%21Concat.php/class/Concat) plugin use a flat, non-associative array of strings as source, you are trying to concat a nested array of JSON objects. You could try to [subprocess](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21migrate%21src%21Plugin%21migrate%21process%21SubProcess.php/class/SubProcess) your `tags` to only fetch/concat the `displayName` from them

Comment: How does this work? Example?